# Report in xls format: row and column auto adjustment

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports* to generate reports in *xls* format. I am trying to auto adjust the column and row with following code.

```
print.getPropertiesMap().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text", "true");
print.getPropertiesMap().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row","true");
print.getPropertiesMap().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column","true");
```

I can't quite figure out why this is not working.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I can't get it to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more property you would need

```
"net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" to "false"
```

and also set  `isStretchWithOverflow` to false

Comment: can I apply isStretchWithOverflow to all text fields programmatically?